# How to read output of Keras Handwriting Recongition Model in TF Lite Android?

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to implement handwriting text recogontition in my Android App. I found TensorFlow to be a doable solution, so I've tried to create a .tflite Model from the [Handwriting Recognition Model from Keras](https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/)
The tutorial states that it is fully compatible with TF Lite
I managed to create the .tflite model and then in Android intialize the Interpreter with the model. I then ran the Interpreter with a ByteBuffer of a bitmap and the output is a shape of [1,32,81], which is a array of floats. As far as i know the output should just be a String; the prediction text of the given input. How can I get/decode the output to the String I need?

I had a few problems

1. Converting the model to a .tflite but i managed to do it using certain flags as follows:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(prediction_model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tf_lite_model = converter.convert()
open('textRecognitionModel.tflite', 'wb').write(tf_lite_model)
```

2. According to the [docs of TF Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select) you have to use the following dependencies

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
// This dependency adds the necessary TF op support.
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
```

After finally creating a .tflite model file, I then added it to the assets directory of my android app and tried importing it. However, it would crash with no error message, apparently a memory failure. I updated the libraries to the latest version:

```
"org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.11.0"
"org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.11.0"
```

And converted my model to ByteBuffer as follows (I'm not sure if i'm doing it right regarding the native order logic):

```
// fileName is the name of the model file in the assets dir
val inputStream = assetManager.open(filename)
val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()
inputStream.copyTo(output, 1024)
val file = output.toByteArray()
val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(file.size)
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
bb.put(file)
return bb
```

And finally the initialization of the Interpreter API is finally working.
I then run the interpreter on a ByteBuffer of a Bitmap. So I'm expecting that the model will read the input and give prediction text (a String) as output. However, the output is a [1,32,81] shape, so i created an array to read the output and ran the Interpreter on it:

```
val output = Array(1) {
    Array(32) {
        FloatArray(81)
    }
}
// byteBuffer: ByteBuffer of bitmap
interpreter.run(byteBuffer, output)
```

And the output is an array of floats which I don't understand what this means. Shouldn't it just be a String? I've attached a screenshot of the output array[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxWPz.png)

Can someone please help me??
I would highly appreciate any tips or solutions :)

Comment: The code of model doesnt return the string. There is another function `decode_batch_predictions(pred)` in your reference link which takes your predicted output and returns the string. Unfortunately the function is not part of model and hence you wont be able to directly use it.

Answer (score 0):

Before converting the `prediction_model` to tflite format, you need to add a custom layer at the end and then convert it into tflite format.

```
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
) # This line is present in the handwriting_recognition notebook.

def CTCDecoder():
  def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    # Use greedy search. For complex tasks, you can use beam search
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]
    # Iterate over the results and get back the text
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        #print(res)
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text

  return tf.keras.layers.Lambda(decode_batch_predictions, name='decode')

decoded_pred_model = keras.models.Model(prediction_model.input, outputs=CTCDecoder()(prediction_model.output))
```

Now you can convert `decoded_pred_model` to your tflite format and use it. CTCDecoder is the custom layer added on top of `prediction_model.output` to decode the predictions with shape [1,32,81] into texts.

Comment: Thanks @MSS, In this line
`results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]`
I get following error: 
`
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "decode" (type Lambda).

Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for '{{node decode/CTCGreedyDecoder}} = CTCGreedyDecoder[T=DT_FLOAT, blank_index=-1, merge_repeated=true](decode/Log, decode/Cast)' with input shapes: [32,?,81], [].

Call arguments received by layer "decode" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 81), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=False
`

Comment: Is this error coming in android while feeding the image or inside notebook ?

Comment: No, in Python when i run the .py in console. If it's possible, could you perhaps start a chat and we can continue there?

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250375/ctcdecoder-issue

Comment: Sorry, apparantly I need 20 reputation to chat and it's not possible

Comment: i used the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220052/9061528
And i'm able to generate a model with decoded output
The output now is an array of type INT64 (long). 
Can you help me as to how I can read it in java/android?

Comment: The complete solution is given in https://github.com/tulasiram58827/ocr_tflite/blob/main/colabs/KERAS_OCR_TFLITE.ipynb  with facility to load pretrained weights. Use it to save a model in tflite format for your use.