# How can I add the decode_batch_predictions() method into the Keras Handwriting Recognition OCR model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, decode, tensorflow-lite

I need to add the `decode_batch_predictions()` method to the output of the [Keras Handwriting Recognition OCR model](https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition). The reason for that is that I want to convert the model to TF Lite and I want the output to be decoded since I didn't find any way to decode the output on TF Lite in Android. I already saw a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068303/how-can-i-add-the-decode-batch-predictions-method-into-the-keras-captcha-ocr-m) for a similar Keras model but it wouldn't work for this model.
I have not much knowledge in Python so it's difficult for me to adapt the answers on that post for this model so I would really appreciate any help, thanks!

I tried using the code from that post but it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the notebook for model given in your link, make the following changes after `prediction_model`:

```
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    model.get_layer(name="image").input, model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
) # This line is present in the handwriting_recognition notebook.

def CTCDecoder():
  def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    # Use greedy search. For complex tasks, you can use beam search
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]
    # Iterate over the results and get back the text
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        #print(res)
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text

  return tf.keras.layers.Lambda(decode_batch_predictions, name='decode')

decoded_pred_model = keras.models.Model(prediction_model.input, outputs=CTCDecoder()(prediction_model.output))
```

Convert the `decoded_pred_model` to a .tflite and use it in android.

Comment: Thanks @MSS, In this line
`results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :max_length]`
I get following error: 
`
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "decode" (type Lambda).

Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for '{{node decode/CTCGreedyDecoder}} = CTCGreedyDecoder[T=DT_FLOAT, blank_index=-1, merge_repeated=true](decode/Log, decode/Cast)' with input shapes: [32,?,81], [].

Call arguments received by layer "decode" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 81), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=False
`

Comment: Is this error coming in android ?